# NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate doesn't fire fetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have `UITableViewController`

```
@interface ListViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

...

@end
```

but it doesn't fire `-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ListViewController : UITableViewController<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> ... end
```

assing delegate

Comment: also in viewdidload, set nsfetchcontroler.delegate = self;

Comment: I found it, I change fetchedResultsController.delegate = self; to self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self; Thank you